# EaselJS spritesheet animation makes background disappear

Tags: animation, canvas, mask, sprite-sheet, easeljs

I am working on a game using EaselJS, and I am still trying the functions provided by this great library.

What I may need is Alphamaskfilter class & Spritesheet class.

Currently, I have a canvas like this:

```
<canvas id = 'container3' width = 320px; height = 480px; 
style = 'outline: 2px solid; margin-right: 10px;float:left;'></canvas>
```

and in my script, I have draw a rect with blue color:

```
var ctx3 = document.getElementById('container3').getContext('2d');
ctx3.beginPath();
ctx3.rect(0,0,320,480);
ctx3.fillStyle = 'blue';
ctx3.fill();
```

So now I have a blue color 320*480 canvas. And now I have a sprite sheet to animate on it, 
here is the sprite and code I wrote:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/RcoWY.png

PS: the sprite frame is 200*200 FYI.

```
stage = new createjs.Stage(document.getElementById('container3'));
var test = new Image();
test.src = 'trans_blackball.png';

test.onload = function(){
            var sprite = new createjs.SpriteSheet({
                images: [test],
                frames: {width: 200, height: 200},
                animations: {
                    born: [0,3,0]
                }
            });

            var animation = new createjs.BitmapAnimation(sprite);
            animation.gotoAndPlay("born");
            animation.x = 10;
            animation.y = 10;
            animation.currentFrame = 0;

            stage.addChild(animation);

            createjs.Ticker.addListener(window);
            createjs.Ticker.useRAF = true;
            createjs.Ticker.setFPS(10);


}

function tick(){
   stage.update();
}
```

**Okay, my question is: I expect an animation of an enlarging black circle on a blue background(rect), but what I got is firstly the canvas is blue, but for a certain mini-second after, the whole canvas became white, and the animation is running on the white background, what is the reason of this and how can I solve it?**

Here is two points that may help:

1. I am working with chrome, and I check with F12 & console, the fillStyle of the canvas is still blue even it appears white after the sprite animation start
2. If I set the canvas background property to blue instead of drawing a blue rect on it, everything's fine!!

   ```
   <canvas id = 'container3' width = 320px; height = 480px; 
   style = 'background: blue; outline: 2px solid; margin-right:
   10px;float:left;'></canvas>
   ```

   but clearly this is not what I want...
3. The problem can be solved as well by not using native canvas rect but use EaselJS's Shape to draw the rect:

   ```
   var shape = new createjs.Shape();
   shape.graphics.beginFill("#ff0000").drawRect(0, 0, 320, 480);
   stage.addChild(shape);
   ```

   But I still wanna know why the native rect drawing code is not working...

**Please bare my bad english and thanks for reading and any attempt to help...I can elaborate more if there is anything unclear in the situation..thanks!**

Answer (score 0):

`createjs.Stage.update()` will clear the canvas-contents by default before rendering the new frame.

The reason for this is one the one hand the technical behaviour of `canvas`, the canvas is basically just an image of pixels, you cannot have real 'layers' and say "I just want to remove/update this one object" - you just can modify the flattened pixels of the frame or remove everything and redraw it(which is safer, easier to achieve, and actually fast enough performance-whise. And on the other hand, it makes sense to make consistent use of a framework like EaselJS, and not do some parts with the framework and some parts without it, this would result in a big mess at the end.

So, the right solution is to go with ***3.***

You can set `myStage.autoClear = false;` to prevent the Stage from [autoClear](http://www.createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/classes/Stage.html#property_autoClear)ing the canvas on every `update()` but I don't think this will suit your needs in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend instead using the EaselJS Shape class to make your blue box. If it part of the EaselJS display list, it will be drawn with the other content.

`javascript
var shape = new createjs.Shape();
shape.graphics.beginFill("blue").drawRect(0,0,320,480);
stage.addChild(shape);`